# Node.JS Transform Streams - Data loss

Tags: node.js, stream, buffer

I've got some stream problems with my code that I don't know how to fix.

Code excerpt: http://gist.github.com/5689522

Essentially, I've got a couple of transform streams inside a parent transform stream, but i've got problems passing along the data because I'm using push on the first stream (S0) which is not being transformed, and therefore just pusing data directly to the second stream (S1), and causing errors. Normally I would use `.pipe()` to connect streams, but I can't see how to do that from inside the transform stream as I want to pipe the input, not the output, and the `_transform` function only gives a single chunk (buffer) as an argument.

Any ideas how to do something like this?

Answer (score 3):

you need to collect chunks together

```
var data='', tstream = new stream.Transform();
tstream._transform = function (chunk, encoding, done) {
    data += chunk.toString();
    done();
};
```

then reassign *_flush* function:

```
tstream._flush = function (done) {
    data += 'hola muheres';
    this.push(data);
    done();
};
```

so all together:

```
req.pipe(anotherstream).pipe(tstream).pipe(response);
```

=> "somedata"
=> "somedatahola muheres"

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for `push`:

> Note: This function should be called by Readable implementors, NOT by consumers of Readable streams.

Since you are not calling that in the implementation of `ParserStream`, you should not be calling `_s0Stream.push`, you should be doing `_s0Stream.write`. You probably want to also pass your `done` callback in that case too.